# How to dynamically add css style to pseudo classes in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a React component that shows multiple images stored in a database, where below each thumbnail image there is a button linking to its dedicated page. Now, I would like each button to show the dominant color of the image as background on hover. I already have the colors stored in database (`artwork.palette.DOMINANT`), but struggles to pass the hex code to the React component.

The problem is, inline style cannot set properties of pseudo selectors like `a:hover`, and because the color is dynamically fetched with the `artwork` object, I can not set it in a global and static css. Is there a way to set component-scoped style in React? Presumably like `<style scoped>...</style>`.

Here is my code, I only kept the gist of it for simplicity's sake.

```
const ImageBox = ({ artwork }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={artwork.resources.THUMBNAIL} alt={artwork.title} />
            </div>
            <div className="caption">
                <span>By {artwork.artist}.</span>
            </div>
            <div className="button">
                <a href="!#" style={{ color: artwork.palette.DOMINANT }}>
                    Details
                </a>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: Are you using .css/.scss/.less files for styles or CSS-in-JS?

Comment: @PramodMali Thanks for replying. All my `className`s come from the global `import "./App.css"` in App.js (generated by create-react-app), and the rest is just inline style. I am new to react and just experimenting with basic stuff, so I am open to learn .scss/.less or anything of the sort if they can get the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use JS to modify the global properties of CSS.

1. Declare properties in `index.css` or `App.css` and add your basic styles that will utilize these variables.

```
:root {
  --color-surface: white;
}

button {
  background: var(--color-surface);
}
```

2. Modify these properties using JS(`onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`). i.e.

```js
//onMouseEnter
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color-surface", "black");

//onMouseLeave
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color-surface", "white")
```

There a few references you can follow:

[Blog](https://medium.com/better-programming/theming-react-with-css-variables-bb9efd5f1918) and [CodSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-theming-pn0to?file=/src/App.js)

Note: *Not sure if it's a good practice(I haven't seen in projects I've worked on), I would recommend using [CSS-in-JS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.4.0) or libraries such as [styled component](https://styled-components.com/).*

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I directly went for the CSS-in-JS approach and it worked like a charm. And it's a simple and easy-to -understand solution. Many thx :D

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @PramodMali, I found the CSS-in-JS approach as a elegant way to solve this problem. For anyone who stumbles upon the same struggle in the future, here's how I solved it with `react-css`:

```
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

const useStyles = (dominantColor = "#fff") =>
    createUseStyles({
        toDetailPage: {
            color: dominantColor,
            "&:hover": {
                color: "#000",
                background: dominantColor,
            }
        }
    });
```

After defining the style generator, use it to dynamically set classes in component:

```
const ImageBox = ({ artwork }) => {
    const classes = useStyles(artwork.palette.dominant)();
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={artwork.resources.THUMBNAIL} alt={artwork.title} />
            </div>
            <div className="caption">
                <span>By {artwork.artist}.</span>
            </div>
            <div className="button">
                <a href="!#" className={classes.toDetailPage}>
                    Details
                </a>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

This will then generate dynamic classes on render, for instance `detailsButton-0-2-7`, which applies the properties passed to the generator function when defining `classes`.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for how to set styles dynamically. My main intention was to write a style for hover. Using state to track whether it is hovered or not is good but that will cost render for each update. So I thought How I can solve it with out any state change. I end up doing this and it works perfectly.

```js
<a
  target='_blank'
  href="#"
  onMouseOver={(e) => e.target.style.color = 'red'}
  onMouseOut={(e) => e.target.style.color = ''}
>
    This is my link
</a>
```